# How to tell an agent that some actions in the action space are currently not available in gym?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym

1. As the simplest case, I define an action space to be `spaces.Discrete(3)`, but sometimes, 0 is unavailable, agent only can sample from 1 and 2. And sometimes, 2 unavailable, or, 1 and 2 are unavailable. How can I tell the agent that some choices are not available?

(Note: By `unavailable`, I means that this action is impossible, will not happen, and that it's results is undefined; rather than a bad choice which results in a negative reward.)

2. In reality, I have `MultiDiscrete` action spaces, and some of the actions sometimes are not available(just as in question 1). Or even worse, actions chosen from those spaces must satisfy some condition, for example, a `Discrete 2 - Discrete 2` `MultiDiscrete` action spaces must satisfy a function that `f(a1, a2) <= 1` where `a1` is sampled from the first `Discrete 2` space, and `a2` is sampled from the second `Discrete 2` space. But the `f` here is a complex function which is not as simple as a `+`, but a function which related to the current state. If this is the case, how can I tell the agent that some choices are currently unavailable?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how you can specify that when constructing the action space, but you can sample the action samples with conditions. For your example 1, you can use a `while` loop to keep sampling from the action space, and only return the result if the condition is satisfied.

```
from gym import spaces

def conditional_action():
    while True:
        a = spaces.Discrete(3).sample()
        if a == 0:
            continue
        break
    return a

print(conditional_action())
```

Using the same logic, you can apply this to other action_space to sample with conditions, for example, I have a MultiDiscrete action space that I specify the sum of the array should not be more than 6.

```
def conditional_action():
    while True:
        a = spaces.MultiDiscrete([6 for i in range(3)]).sample()
        if sum(a) > 6:
            continue
        break
    return a

print(conditional_action())
```